# How to Track E-mail read receipts using google analytics-4 , via image pixel tracking technique?

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I want to track the read receipts of the emails . using google analytics-4 , appscript and gsheets .

till now i have implemented

1. image pixel tracking technique but the email app (in my case gmail) does not allow the script to load , that is embedded in the html template of the email .
2. Also implemented using a website hosted on google sites , but that is also not working.

Comment: Did you "Allow images" in your gmail app?